# Text messages/website displayed on MAC

Tags: iphone

I'm currently going through a divorce, and I do not want my text messages or browser history showing up on my wife's (used to be our) Mac from my iPhone.  I'm not hiding anything, but since we are no longer together she does not need to know what is going on in my life.  Since I don't have access to the computer, how can I turn off this feature?

Comment: I'm don't think it'll work for OS X because of the nature of how it's designed, but for iOS, [you can remotely deregister iMessage.](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage)

Comment: Thanks, but here is the kicker.  I live in the mountain and IMessage is the only way I can receive/send texts messages because I don't get a signal.  Any other ideas?  I should of mentioned in my message that I have a IPhone 6S, not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: You need to have an iCloud account that your wife does not have the password for it is this account that is synced not the phone directly to the Mac

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to remotely prevent the Mac (which your wife has in her possession) from receiving additional data.

On your iPhone, go to Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding, and turn off forwarding for the Mac.
Source: http://www.macworld.com/article/2997176/software-web/how-to-remove-old-devices-from-text-forwarding-on-an-iphone.html

To stop browser history from syncing across devices, also sign the Mac out of your iCloud account. You can do this by signing into https://www.icloud.com/, visiting Settings, and removing the Mac from My Devices.

You may also want to change your iCloud account's password, which you can access via the iCloud account settings (Apple ID > Manage).

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings -> iCloud -> turn off anything you don't want synced. As for messages, you must sign out of the current account by going to settings -> iMessage -> tap the Apple ID. Click sign out.